# It will be true that if $\theta_{n} \to \theta$, then $\cos {\theta_n} \to \cos {\theta}$.

Tags: real-analysis

It will be true that if $\theta_{n} \to \theta$, then $\cos {\theta_n} \to \cos {\theta}$.

I have looked for some counterexample for this statement but I have not found it. So I tried to prove this statement using the definition directly, but I couldn't.
So I want to know some justification for the truth or falsity of this statement.

Answer (score 4):

Since $\cos$ is a continuous function, whenever $\lim_{n\to\infty}\theta_n=\theta$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\cos(\theta_n)=\cos(\theta)$.

Comment: By definition (or at least equivalent to it).

Comment: I feel that the fact that $\cos$ is continuous is a result of what we want to prove, unless it is obvious that $\cos$ is continuous by some other argument other than common knowledge

Comment: Proving that $\cos$ is continuous depends upon how you define it. For instance, if you define $\cos\theta$ as $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}\theta^{2n}$, then the continuity of $\cos$ follows from general properties of power series.